# AutoUpdaterDotNet Trying to update but new file never replaces the old one

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, auto-update

So I am using `AutoUpdaterDotNET` to handle updates for a standalone .exe ( it doesn't need to be packaged into an installer at all ). I am also using WPF, so I had to edit the `OnDownloadComplete()` function to use `Environment.Exit(0)`.

So the program goes out and downloads the new file to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\Filename.exe`, then closes and relaunches the app from `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\Filename.exe`. I have the original executable file located on the desktop.

I have search high and low for a solution to this with no luck. I am new to C# and Visual Studio but I just want the file that is on the desktop to be replaced with the one that is downloaded and then relaunch it from the one on the desktop.  Can anyone provide advice?

Comment: OMG my eyes refuse to read your question. Please post some code or at least use some punctuation

Comment: From what I have read on the scarse docs it seems that this tool works expecting an installer, not a runnable application. Infact just after the download the downloaded file is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a step here.  If you want the app to be located on the desktop,

1. Download the new file
2. Close the app
3. Copy the file over the old .exe file
4. Open the app.

Obviously, these steps would need to be accomplished by a second process (`AutoUpdateDotNET`? or write your own?) Otherwise, I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: You are correct. The AutoUpdatetDotNET automatically opens the downloaded app upon completion. I guess I am missing the copy the app over the old before the AutoUpdateDotNET tries to reopen from the downloaded location.

Comment: I guess my problem is Closing the App, then copying over the new app, then relaunching it. I wouldn't even know where to begin to attempt to write my own.